# Google Chrome Extension: Code does not copy all links from tabs from current Window

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I've tried to create a google chrome extension with the function to copy all links from all tabs within the window. But it only copies and exports the tab where I execute the function.

```
function extractLinks() {
  chrome.windows.getAll({populate:true}, function(windows) {
    let links = [];
    windows.forEach(function(window) {
      window.tabs.forEach(function(tab) {
        if (tab.url) {
          links.push(tab.url);
        }
      });
    });
    let csvContent = "data:text/csv;charset=utf-8," + links.join("\n");
    let encodedUri = encodeURI(csvContent);
    let link = document.createElement("a");
    link.setAttribute("href", encodedUri);
    link.setAttribute("download", "tablinks.csv");
    document.body.appendChild(link);
    link.click();
  });
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function () {
  document.getElementById("extractBtn").addEventListener("click", extractLinks);
});
```

Comment: Add `"permissions": ["tabs"]` to manifest.json.

Comment: You must be on the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) before asking questions.